# A Regex in Javascript challenge

Tags: javascript, regex

I have strings that look like this:

```
list_test_prod_01

list_test_prod_02
```

or another example is

```
sub_test_prod_feature

sub_test_prod_feature_round_edge
```

etc

I would like to know if there is a way to use a regex for a search and replace action that will find the last occurance of the underscore character in the string (as the examples show that is not a fixed number), then go to the end of the word and append another string to it.

for example `sub_test_prod_feature` becomes `sub_test_prod_feature_typed`.

There could be multiple occurences of these so called keywords in a full page of text.

Hopefully someone has a great idea, I'm not the best with regex and regular search and replace code with indexof, substrings etc so far hasn't been fail safe in large amounts of text.

Thanks!

Comment: hm can't you just append your text to the string with a simple concatenation operator ? I don't see why you have to use regexp ? like, `list_test_prod_01` should be `list_test_prod_01_typed` or `list_test_prod_typed` ?

Comment: I suggest you add a sample where the underscore actually matters : in the only input -> output sample you provided, it looks like your problem can simply be solved by concatenating a string at the end of the input.

Comment: I'd expect to see some RegExp in a question tagged with [regex], but no ..?

Comment: The problem really boils down to finding any word on a word boundary consisting of `[a-zA-Z_]` with at least one `_` (that this cannot be the final character is not made explicit from the problem statement) and then appending `_typed` to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JS, try

```
str.replace(/(\b[a-z]+(_[a-z]+)+\b)/gi, '$1_typed');
```

Example:

**Edit**
In case strings like _xyz have to be replaced as well then the regex is `(\b[a-z]*(_[a-z]+)+\b)`

```js
var result = 'a_b_c d_e f_g_ hij k_l_m,n_o_p_q _xyz'
             .replace(/(\b[a-z]+(_[a-z]+)+\b)/gi, '$1_typed');
console.log(result); // "a_b_c_typed d_e_typed f_g_ hij k_l_m_typed,n_o_p_q_typed _xyz"

var result2 = 'a_b_c d_e f_g_ hij k_l_m,n_o_p_q _xyz'
             .replace(/(\b[a-z]*(_[a-z]+)+\b)/gi, '$1_typed');
console.log(result2); // "a_b_c_typed d_e_typed f_g_ hij k_l_m_typed,n_o_p_q_typed _xyz_typed"
```

Comment: What about a the following word: `_xyz`?

Comment: Excluded from the results on purpose. But if it has to be replaced as well, then it's even more simple :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"sub_test_prod_feature  xxxx sub_test_prod_feature".replace(/_(\w+)/gi, "$1_typed")
"subtest_prod_feature_typed  xxxx subtest_prod_feature_typed"
```

Comment: `\w` includes the `_` character so in the case of `sub_test_prod_feature` $1 is `test_prod_feature`, so it works anyway. It is, however, not clear from the problem statement whether `_` cannot be the final character in the word (nothing in the statement says it can't). Your code will not match `abc_`.

Comment: Well spotted. Replacing the + with a * will resolve that limitation.

Comment: Also, `\w` matches things besides alpha characters, such as numbers. `[a-z]` might be a better candidate.

Comment: I guess it all boils down to the current status of this request "This question needs details or clarity."

Comment: Exactly right!!

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log('_def abc_def abc_def_xyz abc_'.replace(/((?:\b[a-z_]*)_[a-z]*\b)/gi, '$1_typed'))
```

Or, if the final `_` must be followed by at least one alpha character:

```js
console.log('_def abc_def abc_def_xyz abc_'.replace(/((?:\b[a-z_]*)_[a-z]+\b)/gi, '$1_typed'))
```